Creating incremental slides for animated elements from existing powerpoint file using Google Slides API
as the title mentioned. I am having a raw pptx file that contains just one slide but with multiple animated elements in it. I want to split them into individual slides so that i can transform them into static images. I am currently using NodeJS and using Google Slides API for uploading. Can anyone give me a helping hand as ChatGPT is not really useful in this problem. Thank you !
